# How to publish artifacts in gradle 4.4 in android studio (Upload APK to nexus)?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, upload, snapshot

I am trying to upload my APK to Nexus repository.
Below code work fine until I have change gradle version

from

> classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3' 
>   distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.3-all.zip
>   mCompileSdkVersion=23  mBuildToolsVersion='25.0.0'

**To**

> classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0' 
>   distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-all.zip
>   mCompileSdkVersion=27  mBuildToolsVersion='27.0.0'

After changing versions same code is not work I am not able to understand where I found an error, Terminal not showing any error message but my APK is not uploaded in given location

following is the current configuration of my App build.gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'maven'    

task uploadRelease (type: Upload){
    configuration = project.getConfigurations().getByName('archives');
    repositories {
        mavenDeployer {
            repository(  url: "http://XXXXXXXX:8081/nexus/XXXXXXXX/repositories/releases"  ) {
                authentication(userName: "MyuserName", password: "Mypassword")
            }
            pom.project {
                version "${android.defaultConfig.versionName}"
                artifactId "Collection"
                name "xxxxxxxx"
                groupId "com.xxxxxxxx.mobile.xxxxxxxx.collections"
            }
        }
    }
}

task uploadSnapshot (type: Upload){
    configuration = project.getConfigurations().getByName('archives');

    repositories {
        mavenDeployer {
            repository(  url: "http://XXXXXXXX:8081/nexus/XXXXXXXX/repositories/snapshots"  ) {
                authentication(userName: "MyuserName", password: "Mypassword")
            }
            pom.project {
                version "${android.defaultConfig.versionName}-SNAPSHOT"
                artifactId "Collection"
                name "Collection"
                groupId "com.xxxxxxxx.mobile.xxxxxxxx.collections"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I use Command as - `gradle assemblerelease uploadsnapshot`

to build and upload APK but It does not work for gradle 4.4 Please let me know what went wrong

Comment: use `gradle assemblerelease uploadsnapshot --debug --info --stacktrace` to gather more informations and post the error logs.

Answer (score 1):

The new Android Gradle Plugin version 3.+ relocate the apk to a different paths compared to 2.2.3.

Some errors may happen at below line

```
configuration = project.getConfigurations().getByName('archives');
```

Use `gradle assemblerelease uploadsnapshot --debug --info --stacktrace` to gather more information and analyse the error logs.

The older apk location is

```
build/outputs/apk/*.apk
```

the apk location for AGP 3.x is

```
build/outputs/apk/<flavour>/<buildtype>/<name>-<buildtype>.apk
```

so

```
def apk = file('build/outputs/apk/release/iMobility-release.apk')
artifacts {
    archives apk
}
```

This is to overwrite the paths of archives with the correct apk location.

Comment: I have use this command got error log like "Fail due to above error " and there is nothing error above

Comment: when I use this    -------------def apk = file('build/outputs/apk/release/iMobility-release.apk')
artifacts {
    archives apk
}   

It work for me but dont know why

Comment: From AGP 3.0+, the apk location is placed into a path according to build variant, e.g. outputs/apk/<variant name>/iMobility-release.apk', which is different from the older 2.x+ version.

Answer (score 0):

Not the actual answer but what work for me is

Put this line below your

```
task uploadSnapshot (type: Upload){
    configuration = project.getConfigurations().getByName('archives');

    repositories {
        mavenDeployer {
            repository(  url: "http://XXXXXXXX:8081/nexus/XXXXXXXX/repositories/snapshots"  ) {
                authentication(userName: "MyuserName", password: "Mypassword")
            }
            pom.project {
                version "${android.defaultConfig.versionName}-SNAPSHOT"
                artifactId "Collection"
                name "Collection"
                groupId "com.xxxxxxxx.mobile.xxxxxxxx.collections"
            }
        }
    }
 } 

def apk = file('build/outputs/apk/release/iMobility-release.apk')
artifacts {
    archives apk
}
```

Can any one explain this why ? and have a better option then this ?